# Azure mobile services UpdateAsync gives me 404 error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am working on xamarin forms and using azure mobile services. When I try to update a record the UpdateAsync does not work and gives me a 404 error.

While debugging I noticed the following line from the debugger:

```
<b> Requested URL: </b>/tables/Customer/10k<br><br>
```

10k is the ID.

When I use postman with the link above, it give me back the same 404 error. However, If I used the link `/tables/Customer?id=10k` it works in postman.

This is the error message from VS.

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>The resource cannot be found.</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
            </head>

            <body bgcolor="white">

                    <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

                    <h2> <i>The resource cannot be found.</i> </h2></span>

                    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

                    <b> Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
                    <br><br>

                    <b> Requested URL: </b>/tables/Customer/10k<br><br>

                    <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

                    <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3282.0

                    </font>

            </body>
        </html>
        <!-- 
        [HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/tables/Customer/10k&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.
           at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
           at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
           at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
           at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
           at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
           at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
           at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
           at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
           at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
        --><!--
        This error page might contain sensitive information because ASP.NET is configured to show verbose error messages using &lt;customErrors mode="Off"/&gt;. Consider using &lt;customErrors mode="On"/&gt; or &lt;customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/&gt; in production environments.-->
```

Comment: I also noticed a lot of MVC handler in the error message . I never worked on ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution but I ran into another problem .

I had this line on top of customer controller

```
[Route("tables/Customer")]
```

I removed it and edited

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

to this

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "tables/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

but now when I update from client it gives me bad request error .

**Update**

I fixed the bad request error.
in my backend customer class i had datetime? and in my client customer class i have datetime .. i removed the ? .

now i am getting internal server error .

**Update 2**

In my database the record i was trying to update had some NULL columns , I filled them up and now im getting bad request again .

**Update 3**

I got it to work . I had two primary keys in the database . When I called the UpdateAsync I only passed one key in the object . when I passed the two keys it worked .

```
Customer customer = new Customer
            {
                Id="10k", // first primary key
                CustomerId=12, // second primary key
                FirstName = FirstNamelbl.Text.ToString(),
                LastName = LastNamelbl.Text.ToString(),
                DOB = doblbl.Date,
                Email = Emaillbl.Text.ToString(),
                Sex = GenderGroup.SelectedItem.ToString()
            };
            // save customer input 
            await manager.UpdateCustomerRecordAsync(customer);
```

the manager

```
public async Task UpdateCustomerRecordAsync(Customer customer)
        {
            try
            {
                await customerTable.UpdateAsync(customer);
            }
            catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException msioe)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Invalid sync operation: {0}", new[] { msioe.Message });

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Sync error: {0}", new[] { e.Message });
            }
        }
```